# How to count input values

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

For (not working) example:

```
SELECT NEXTVAL
FROM DUAL
  CONNECT BY level <= COUNT('234234', '234235', '32523')
```

I want that `COUNT('234234', '234235', '32523')` would return `3` as there 3 input values.

I can't change the string `'234234', '234235', '32523'`. It will always be like `'nnn', 'nnn', 'nnn' ...` But other parts of the query can be changed fully

Is it possible?

Comment: How are the values ('234234', '234235', '32523') getting into your query?

Comment: @MarkBannister it's some automation system. I can't change that

Comment: Can you amend your question to show which bits of the query can be changed, and which bits are supplied by the automation system?

Comment: @MarkBannister all parts of query can be changed except the string format. So only this part can't be changed `'234234', '234235', '32523'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you actually have a string, you can use string functions for this.  For your example, this returns the number of elements:

```
select (length('234234, 234235, 32523') - length(replace('234234, 234235, 32523', ',', '')) + 1
from dual
```

If you want this in a table, why not just do:

```
with t as (select '23434' as v from dual union all select '234235' from dual union all select '32523' from dual)
select count(*)
from t
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But due of some reasons the string format `'234234', '234235', '32523'` can't be changed. So it will be always like `'nnn', 'nnn'`, I can't make it like `'nn, nn'`

Comment: @VextoR . . . The embedded single quotes do not matter to the logic.  I just thought leaving them out made it clearer.

Comment: I tried to do this: `SELECT NEXTVAL
FROM DUAL
  CONNECT BY level <= (length('234234', '234235', '32523') - length(replace('234234', '234235', '32523', ',', '')) + 1` no luck: `00909. 00000 -  "invalid number of arguments"`

Comment: @VextoR . . . Do you have one string or three strings?  If you have three strings, then how are you passing them to Oracle?  The `length()` function takes an argument which is a single string.

Comment: you're right, the number of strings is variable. These strings are passed to Oracle by some automation and I want to count them. They come in format `'nn', 'nn'` and I can't change that...

Comment: @VextoR . . . If you can construct a query, try the second solution.

Comment: I modified your answer to: `... connect by level <= (length(replace(q'$'1','2','3','5'$', '''', '')) - length(replace(replace(q'$'1','2','3','5'$', '''', ''), ',', '')) + 1)` now it works :)

Answer (score 1):

Because the string is begin feed in from an application, it makes if difficult to show an example.

Something along the lines of:

```
select length( regexp_replace('''234234'', ''234235'', ''32523''', '[^,]+','')) + 1 from dual
```